# How to count no. of days between 2 dates from calendar in string format vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have 2 aspx calendar(AbsenceStartDateCal & AbsenceEndDateCal) which will pass the date value to textbox with .cs codes as follow:

```
Protected Sub AbsenceEndDateCal_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AbsenceEndDateCal.SelectionChanged
    Dim date2 As DateTime = New System.DateTime
    date2 = AbsenceEndDateCal.SelectedDate
    tbAbsenceEndDate.Text = date2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

End Sub
```

In my pageload, i want to count no.of days to display as a label btw the 2 textbox value. I tried with the following code but it doesn't work with this error  "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
    Dim startDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(tbAbsenceStartDate.Text)
    Dim endDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(tbAbsenceEndDate.Text)
    Dim ts As New TimeSpan
    ts = endDate.Subtract(startDate)
    lblnoOfDays.Text = ts.Days
```

So i am not sure cos im new to VB. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ParseExact method and specify the formatting you want.
You get invalid formatting because you are probably trying to set day or month values which exceed the range defined under the current formatting.

Example:

```
Dim startDateString = "12/01/2015"
Dim endDateString = "14/01/2015"

Dim startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDateString, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(endDateString, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Dim ts As New TimeSpan
ts = endDate.Subtract(startDate)

Dim dayDiff = ts.Days
```

Comment: i don't want to hard code like Dim startDateString = "12/01/2015" as i want to take the value from the selected date from the calendar

Comment: so just replace it with your tbAbsenceStartDate.Text

Comment: The idea is to use the ParseExact with the formatting, you should figure out how to pass your arguments from your code

Comment: yeah i tried that but still got the same error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: This means your formatting is Different from the one I specified in code,
For example, is the month represented by a single digit or two? E.g. for January 1 vs. 01, notice the formatting asks for two

Comment: my textbox value will store as 11/02/2015 which is the correct format .. hmm not sure if the back code of my calendar_selectionchange is correct??

Comment: If you take my piece of code and run it, does it work?

Comment: yes it work..  i believe is the calendar selection change back code not storing as the correct format even though in the textbox it looks like the format.. but i don't know what other ways to convert it..

Comment: Put a break point on ParseExact call. What is the date value the watch shows? maybe the text box adds spaces and you need to trim it? maybe it elimitates Zeros (As mentioned in the January question in the above comment)

Comment: So you need this formatting then
DateTime.ParseExact(startDateString, "dd:mm:yyyy tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: If the "#" is a part of the string, then add it to the format
DateTime.ParseExact(endDateString, "#dd:mm:yyyy tt#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: i tried to put a breakpoint at the calendar selection change back code.. it actually store as #2/11/2015# so i think it should be DateTime.ParseExact(endDateString, "#m/dd/yyyy#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)   but i tried and it didnt work cos the   Dim endDateString = tbAbsenceEndDate.Text get a value of "#12:00:00 AM# which i don't know why

Comment: Let me try to simplify it for you, and afterwards, you will need to figure it on your own. 

When you want to convert a string to a datetime, and you need to sepcify the formatting, a basic rule is to know what the formatting is.

I suggest you figure it out, and just create the format string! if your date conatins a time signature, it should be added to the format, and so on.

Try googling or check MSDN documentation for formatting examples.

If you found my answer useful, please mark it as correct, good luck.